# NODEJS mysql result is undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

Hello i got problem with node mysql.

```
client.on('message', message => {

   var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: config.host,
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      database: config.database
   });

   //con.connect(function (err){ i was try with this
      //if(err) console.log(err); i was try with this
      con.query(`SELECT * FROM servers`, function (err, result){
            result.forEach(row => {
               if(row.guild === message.guild.id){
                 //some code
               }
            }
       }
```

For 20/30 min. everything is okay.
But then i got crash.
I found one solution.

```
client.on('message', message => {

   var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: config.host,
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      database: config.database
   });

      con.query(`SELECT * FROM servers`, function (err, result){
           if(result){
             result.forEach(row => {
               if(row.guild === message.guild.id){
                 //some code
               }
             }
           }else{
                console.log("no result");
           }
       }
```

But then i got only spam "no result" and nothing works.
Someone have idea how to get this still work not only for 20 min?

Comment: Side note: You should create a global connection object. not for each "message" you receive

Comment: @Marc but when i do mysql.createConnection on the top i got connection timeout when i add con.end(); forEach dont wanna work.

Comment: dont close the connection. keep them open and reuse it. close it only when you exit your program

Comment: Then i got timeout for connection.

Comment: What do you mean with timeout ?! You can reuse a existing mysql connection to perform multiple queries. befor you can query the server, wait that the connection is successful.

Comment: I mean when i do createConnection on the top i got crash and text of the crash is "TIMEDOUT" from node mysql. 
You think this [code](https://hastebin.com/imehijuyad.js) will work?

Comment: Yeno. what are you trying ?! where does "client" get defined ? A event listener inseda a query/loop is terrible. A global connect indeed works. And Avoid to fetch all rows just to see if one exists with guild = message.guild.id This should be done in query with "LIKE"

Comment: if the connection times out after a while you might wanna try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331441/mysql-turns-itself-off-after-discord-bot-left-on-for-about-12-hours/64332807#64332807)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connections time out. I wouldn't of thought it would within 30 minutes, but it sounds to me like this is the issue. Instead connect using pool. Also its much better to put this outside the `client.on('message', message => {  });`, then just reference it from inside. Example:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var db_config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mybots-db'
};

var con = mysql.createPool(db_config);
con.getConnection(function (err, con) {
    if (err) {
        connection.release();
        console.log(' Error getting mysql_pool connection: ' + err);
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Connected to Database');
});



client.on('message', message => {
    //Your code here
});
```

As a side-note, if you want to check if you've got a result it can be done easier with `if(typeof result[0] === 'undefined') return console.log("It isn't defined!");`

Comment: Thanks. But when i need to use some data in `client.on('message', message =>` or need to add something to database. How can i do this? Like later? `con.query`?

Comment: @xmxf yes, say you wanted to add every message to the database, inside `client.on('message', message =>`, put `con.query("INSERT INTO tablename (id, message) VALUES (?, ?)"), [message.id, message.content]`

Comment: Ok i tested it. Its works longer so much longer but look at this: [link](https://hastebin.com/nohesemuvi.rb)